# Filling Missing String Values for same Brand Code using Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code in Python to find the missing string values(Product Description) of a brand code. Please look at the Output Image for reference.

I could able to find these missing values in SQL Server using Common Table Expressions. I would like to implement the same in the Python.

As I couldn't get the proper solution in Python I am sharing the SQL Code for reference.

```
;with cte as
(
select 
distinct [Brand Code],[Product Description]
from dbo.Harsha_2
where [Product Description] is not null
)
select 
--t1.F1, 
t1.[Brand Code], t1.[Product Description]
, ISNULL(t1.[Product Description],t2.[Product Description]) [Product Description]
, t1.[WeekNo],t1.[Quantity]

from dbo.Harsha_2 t1
left join cte t2 on t1.[Brand Code]=t2.[Brand Code]
--order by [Brand Code]
```

[image]

Comment: SQL code is useless when you post a python quesiton...., are you using python 2 or 3?(don't tag both!), you didn't post a picture... and what have you tried in python?

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.4, you can see the hyperlink (Image) given above which shows how data looks.

Comment: Where is python code you have tried?